# MongoDb schema design for a "topic -> posts" domain use case

Tags: node.js, mongodb

First of all, i just wanna say that i'm new to mongoDb and coming from a relational "philosophy", probably some assumptions i'm making about how mongoDb works might be wrong. I'm developing a simple project using MEAN stack, it's simple discussion system, where you have Topics and Posts.

To model this use case in MongoDB i come up with 3 ways of doing it:

1. **With embedded documents**

   `{ 
     topicId : ObjectId,
     postsNr : Number,
     posts : [{POST},{}]
   }`

As i understand this options as some drawbacks, the number of posts can get big let's say 500,000 thousand and pushing and pulling elements from the array can impact the performance because the padding factor. Also embedded documents offer less  flexibility than separate collections in terms of sorting and range queries. However for what saw using the aggregation framework, the '$' operator and the $slice it's possible to sort, update a specific post in the array and paginate the posts, correct me if i'm wrong.

2. **Separate collections**

   `{
     topicId : ObjectId,
     postsNr : Number,
   }`

   `{
     postId : ObjectId,
     topicId : ref for topicId,
   }`

Using something like this gives more flexibility, but know comes the problem that's bothering me a lot. Image this simple scenario, a user makes a post, know i want to execute to different writes to the database, one to insert the post in the posts collection and the other to $inc the postsNr in the Topics collection. Knowing that MongoDb doesn't offer transactions it could happen that i insert the post, and then something goes wrong and the postsNr is not incremented, from know on my data will be **inconsistent** and for what i can see is not **eventually inconsistent** because it will no get consistent anymore.

This makes me think that maybe i'm using MongoDB for a use case where it's not appropriate and a relational database will be a better choice, however the fast writes and performance of MongoDB made me think that it could be a good backstore for this problem.

Trying to mitigate this problem, i came up with a new design, but i'm not sure of it's correctness due to lack of experience with mongo.

3. **Mix of embedded and separate collections**

   `{
     topicId : ObjectId,
     postsNr : Number,
     recentPostsNr : Number,
     recentPosts : [{},{}], //Keeps the "X" recent posts, let's say 200
   }`

   `{
     postId : ObjectId,
     topicId : ref for topicId
    }`

Here i store the 200 newest posts in the Topic collection, every time a new post comes in, it get's stored in the recentPosts array, then i can increment the postsNr, this is done atomically because the operations are done in the same collection.

Know comes the tricky part, some point in the future a i need to flush de recentPosts array to the Post collection, this is my ideia for doing without loosing data.

Every time a new post comes in(pseudo-code):

```
 `if (recentPostsNr >= 200){
    //Now push 180 from the recentPosts array to the Posts collection with addToSet
    $addToSet()
    findAndModify() =>  remove 180 posts recentPosts {}, keep 20 for retrieving and alter the recentPostsNr to 20
  }

  //Push the new post to the recentPosts array and inc the posts nr
  $update($inc,$push)
```

Using this technique i get the good of both worlds. I move the posts to the Post collection with $addToSet operator that doesn't allow duplicates, so i do it once, and something goes wrong before the findAndMofidy() query executes, the next time a post gets inserted it will do the same operation operation because recentPostsNr is still 200, however nothing will happen because $addToSet wont change anything. This time the findAndModify() executes and the recentPosts array and recentPostsNr are updated, the new post is then inserted and postsNr is incremented.

Like i said i don't have the experience in mongo to tell if this really works, or if i'm missing something. It's makes me think that in MongoDb if you need to link documents then it's not the best choice for your problem, unless data consistency is not a problem. Which leads me to this article : http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2013/11/11/why-you-should-never-use-mongodb/

Sorry for the long post, but maybe more MongoDB starters out there have the same doubts as mine, and your answers can help eliminate them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to loose all your previous way of relational thinking.

First discussing the third option (the two collection), in my opinion use only one. Keep a timestamp on a filed and if you need the last X amount, limit the ordered query. Having two equal collections is unnecessary added complexity.

The second idea, the one more "relational" is also messy, you will have to do 2 query's due to the lack of joins in mongo, and you can save work if you only do this in one.

The first one is the greatest, but i thing that to save the positionNr it's hard and could be replaced (again) with timestamp of persistence. This always keep the order, and you can get the position by counting. Also is a post can have multiple topics (I'm not sure if a topic is like a thread in a forum or like a tag of a post),  you can think in save the post as the main document, with the topic in a field like this:

```
{ 
  postContent: {[...]},
  timestamp: ISODATE("..."),
  topic/topics :[X1,X2,...]
}
```

And keep a index in the topic to improve the speed of searches of post of topics.